# I need to format date value in javascript code

Tags: javascript

In laravel 5, jquery 3, app  I use gijgo Datepicker with output format

```
        $('#check_in_datepicker').datepicker({    
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            format: 'dd mmmm, yyyy'
        });
```

and I got value in format “09 June, 2020”.
also I need to convert in javascript code date value  into similar format.
What can I use for this and with which format ?

Thanks!

Comment: check this https://momentjs.com/ it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the decision with momentjs lib and format :

```
  moment(dat).format('DD MMMM, YYYY')
```

!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in vanilla Javascript using DOM API you can follow this way:

```js
const  x = document.querySelector("#date-picker");
x.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    
  const inputDate = new Date(Date.parse(event.target.value));
  console.log(inputDate.toDateString())

});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-picker" value="2017-06-01"/>
```

You can even format the date in other ways, by manipulating the string or by using other date methods, check [MDN Docs for more methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I do not use vanilla

Comment: I meant pure javascript. you asked for that. Did not you?